# Wkwebview not loading new request url

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview

I have to reload new request url but if i try to do so it shows previous url. I also tried to load blank before load new request. But it also won't work.

NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com"];

```
webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];   
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]init];
```

// [configuration.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"interOp"];

```
webView_ = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height) configuration:configuration];

webView_.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

webView_.opaque = false;

webView_.navigationDelegate = self;
webView_.UIDelegate = self;

[webView_ loadRequest:nsrequest];

[self.containerView addSubview:webView_];
```

Comment: Mr.Devoter may i know what's wrong with question. Why are you guys looking to reduce point of person who work hard to get those. The question is related to issue which i am facing.

Comment: Are you loading a complete url. Your URL must be complete, and valid, in order for this process to work. That means including the `https://` part. If not help please provide some of your codes so that we can help.